# How to handle an exception in .NET Core Razor pages PageModel and stay on same view?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, exception, razor-pages

I am trying to figure out how to wire up exception handling in an ASP.NET Core Razor pages site to allow the user to stay on the same page when an exception occurs with a friendly error message.

Once the user submits the form on the Edit view, call the back end middle-tier to persist the data if they have the proper permissions.  If they don't have proper permissions, a custom validation exception is thrown from the middle-tier.

```
   private readonly IToolsService m_oToolsService;

   public EditModel(IToolsService toolsService)
   {
        m_oToolsService = oToolsService;
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
   {
        var vm = olsService.GetData():

        // Wire up UI with the ViewModel
        return Page();
   }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(ViewModel vm)
    {
        if (false == ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        m_oToolsService.SaveData(vm);
    }
```

If the call to "m_oToolsService.SaveData(vm);" fails, I'd like to keep the user on the same page with a friendly error message (and with the form data that they tried to post).

I could wrap the OnPost/OnGet ActionMethods with try/catch blocks, however, that gets redundant in all of the PageModels and bloats the code.

I have tried adding custom exception handling Middleware, and while that will catch the custom error, it redirects the user to an error page.

I have also added a custom exception filter similar to the example below but that isn't keeping the user on the page either.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;
    private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;

    public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
        _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // do nothing
            return;
        }

        var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);

        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "/Edit",
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // mark exception as handled
        HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        context.Result = result;
  }
```

No matter what I research, everything seems to point back to using the .NET Core Middleware to redirect to a specific error page.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to handle exceptions but keep the user on the same view?

Comment: Add a property to your Model that holds the exception message and model bind it to your view, place at try-catch inside your Action and if an exception occurs, set the property of your model with the exception details and return the model to the View without doing a RedirectToAction

Comment: Yes, I could add a try-catch block inside each action that calls the middle-tier code and set a property and the model state to invalid and redisplay the view.  To be more specific with my question, I'm wondering if there is a better, more global approach to do similar functionality and not have a try-catch block in each Action method?

Comment: If you can decipher what action was called and from what controller when the exception occurs, couldn't you just redirect to that controller/action with the model with an updated model property of the exception instead of directing to the error page?